# TFVC source control binding invalid when migrating to new workspace

Tags: tfs, binding, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

I'm switching to a new machine and would like to keep my TF files as they are. Thus I simply copied the entire folder to the new machine's (same as the previous one - C:\TF), mapped it to the TF server's root, and attempted to open a solution from the file explorer, hoping that it would bind more or less automatically.

I then ran into issues similar to others that have been described elsewhere, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128730/re-establish-tfs-source-control-bindings) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808879/tfs-binding-invalid-after-upgrading-project-from-vs2015-to-vs2017). VS/TF insist that the binding on the solution and all projects is "invalid".

- Unbinding and re-binding does not work, the binding reappears but remains invalid.
- Recreating the workspace does not work.
- There is nothing funny about the solution file's content.
- The relative paths are correct - if I remove the bindings and try to *add* the files to source control, it overwrites the already existing files in the source control explorer (the item previously appearing as a grayed-out "Not Downloaded" becomes white with an "add" pending change).
- Tried mapping the workspace to a "fake" network drive that pointed to the new machine's hard drive (just in case TF was mixing up the identical paths), still the same.
- Deleting Team Foundation's AppData settings doesn't work.

When I perform a get on the solution folder, though, the binding becomes healthy all of a sudden. In the end I performed the get, deleted all the new files and put the ones from the old machine in their place. VS/TF apparently had no issues with the binding then. It's a rather inconvenient way of achieving that end, though.

I'm forced to conclude that TF *doesn't want* me to bind my own, local files to source control without first performing a get in that workspace, even if the file paths match what is on the server. Question: why is that? Am I doing something conceptually wrong? Doing it the wrong way? Is this behavior an idiot-proof feature of the tool, or just a limitation?

Comment: Yeah everytime I have switched to a new laptop I have had to download fresh from TFS. Your experience is the same as mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong :/. | **it's a feature, not a bug**.

The workspace is registered on the VSTS/TFS server as well as in the local workspace cache. After moving the folders over to a new machine (and to the same folder location), you need to tell VSTS/TFS the new computer name these files now reside on.

You have to run `tf vc workspaces /updateComputerName:oldComputerName workspacename` to update the workspace registration on the server.

But I'm afraid you need to do this before overwriting the workspace with a new mapping.

Now I think the only option is to use the Unbind option, save all, then open the source control menu again and rebind all the projects in the solution. Or edit the solution files manually ([there's a tool for it as well](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RonJacobs.CleanProject-CleansVisualStudioSolutionsForUploadi)).

Comment: I was trying to create a new workspace, though (since I'm still working on the old machine while setting up the new one remotely). TF doesn't seem to have an issue identifying that the new workspace is on the new computer, it just doesn't bind anything there until I execute a get.

Comment: Yeah, that is cause the server knows you've never performed a get. So according to it the version of all items is the magic `0` version. If it had been a local workspace instead of a server workspace it would have worked. If you're willing to leave the old machine behind the above command will work. You could try switching to a local workspace or using `tf vc reconcile`.

Comment: TFVC server workspaces track the version of your files in your workspace on the server for non-local workspaces. Hence it's forcing you to perform a get. It believes you don't have any files. The reconcile command performs a compare against local, it could work.

Comment: Hmm. That makes sense (except for the fact that this *is* a local workspace we're talking about). If TF requires a get to generate a "base file version" it can work with, that explains this annoying behavior. Also, when I look at the details of the solution folder, it shows a server version # but not a local version #, which supports the explanation. To me this sounds like a limitation of TF, so I must disagree with the statement in your answer that I'm doing it wrong :)

Comment: @Platedslicer Jessehouwing is right, this behavior is a feature. You could consider submitting a UserVoice at website below for your idea: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30925-team-foundation-server

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT right, thanks for clearing that up. Would you mind writing up an answer with that information (about it being an intended feature) so that hopefully no one else has to spend an hour+ looking it up like me?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't realize he edited it to include that bit.